# ArrayList<String> method return an empty array getting data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my return..since the data required a few second to get downloaded, when the method return the ArrayList, it's still empty. In fact if I put that lines of code `Log.v("array", String.valueOf(partecipantsArrayList));`
first it print 0 and then it print the array filled. So I have to wait before the return statement..is there any way to achieve this?

```
public ArrayList<String> getPartecipantsList(){
    String email = getEmail();
    String groupTitle = getTitleBar();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(email).collection("Group").document(groupTitle);

    docRef.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {


                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();


                        //Extracting participants ArrayList from the document
                        for(Object item : task.getResult().getData().values()) {

                            String[] values = String.valueOf(item).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");

                            for (String value : values){

                                    partecipantsArrayList.add(value);

                            }

                        }
                        partecipantsArrayList.remove(String.valueOf("["));
                        partecipantsArrayList.remove(partecipantsArrayList.size() - 1);
                        Log.v("array", String.valueOf(partecipantsArrayList));

                    }

                })

            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });


    return partecipantsArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is async task you can adjust this code like below.

change the signature of that method to `return void`

```
public void getPartecipantsList();
```

do next action after the on complete

```
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        ...............
                        partecipantsArrayList.remove(String.valueOf("["));
                        partecipantsArrayList.remove(partecipantsArrayList.size() - 1);

                        Log.v("array", String.valueOf(partecipantsArrayList));
                       // do your action by calling next method from here
                      //eg: setResultFromArray(partecipantsArrayList);
                    }
```

do fail action or call method when failures in side the `onFailure`.

```
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                     //......
                }
```

Comment: Yes, now I put the code that manipolate the Array inside the "OnComplete" method and now It works.. thank you!

Comment: @Nicola nice to hear it. Happy coding